# Why \n (linebreak) doesn't work in my console.log?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

It works in my "code snippet" here on this stackoverflow page. But not for my Chrome Devtools. I am using the latest version `Version 110.0.5481.100 (Official Build) (x86_64)` on macOS `13.2.1`.

```js
console.log(234234, "\n\n", 23423)
```

screenshot here:

[image]

Should I change/tweak some settings in my Devtools?

Comment: Why is this a problem? The fact that you can immediately see the string contains characters that would normally be hard to notice is a good thing. It's not like the developer console is a place to shove ASCII art…

Answer (score 0):

In this console statement `console.log(234234, "\n\n", 23423)`, 234234 and 23423 are considered as Numbers and "\n\n" as a String. These are read in the order they are inputted. As the data types are different, they are considered as separate entities and hence, the no newline is added.

Try adding a blank string as the first argument like this: `console.log("", 234234, "\n\n", 23423)`. You will see the linebreak working. If you add a string as first argument, it considers other arguments as substitute strings and the output is considered to be a string.